# Application defined or object defined error vba pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

Respected Expert, I am trying to execute below VBA code for Define my data and refresh the Pivot Table but I Am getting **defined or object defined error-1004**. Please guide me where I am doing mistake on below.

```
Sub Pivot()

Dim shPivot As Worksheet
Dim shData As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim lc As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set shPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set shData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot")

lr = shPivot.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = shPivot.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, 32))


With shData.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache
        .SourceData = rng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
        .Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It generally helps if you tell us where the error occurs! You need to use: `Set rng = shPivot.Range(shPivot.Cells(1, 1), shPivot.Cells(lr, 32))`

Comment: Following @Rory also for `lr = shPivot.Range("A" & shPivot.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I am getting error on **.SourceData = rng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pivot()

Dim shPivot As Worksheet
Dim shData As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim lr As Long
Dim lc As Long
Dim Rng As Range

Set shPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set shData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot")

With shPivot
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, 32))
End With

' set the Pivot Cache with the updated Data Source
' Set PTCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Rng)

' === Option 2 : set the Pivot Cache with the updated Data Source ===
Set PTCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=shPivot.Name & "!" & Rng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, False))

' Set the Pivot Table to existing "PivotTable1" in "Data" sheet
Set PT = shData.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

With PT
    .ChangePivotCache PTCache
    .RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai , I think this answer could do with a bit of explanation - what was OP doing wrong? Also, `With PT` at the end isn't doing anything?

Comment: @CallumDA thanks for the `With PT` part :) about explanation, I've added comments inside the code, from my experience with `PivotTable`s this is the most reliable way to go

Comment: @ShaiRado Sir, I am getting Type mismatch error in **Set PTCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Rng)**

Comment: @sagar if you add `Debug.Print Rng.Address` before this line, what are you getting in the immediate window ?

Comment: @ShaiRado **$A$1:$AF$14999** is reflecting  in the immediate window which is correct range.

Comment: @sagar thanks for reminding me that with large data sets this method is better